# Вызов метода контролера без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть форма с данными, пользователь вводит данные, нажимает отправить и они отправляються в метод в контроллере, производит некоторые действия с базой. НО! это метод не должен ничего возвращать, в смысле, пользователь нажал на кнопку, данные отправились, но визуально ничего не должно происходить. Как это сделать?
сделать метод типа void и вернуть null вернется пустая страница.

```
 return new EmptyResult()
```

Тоже самое.

Comment: Конкретизируйте, что значит "ничего не должно происходить". Не должно происходить смены url в браузере, перезагрузки страницы? Пока под ваше определение лучше всего подходит "сделать ajax-запрос без перезагрузки страницы", но вообще стоит уточнить.

Comment: Ни смены url, ни перезагрузки, ничего.

Comment: Тогда сделайте вызов ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form target="my_frame" method="post" action="... - points to controller action">
...
</form>

<iframe name="my_frame" src="about:blank" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ajax, что-то типа:

Форма:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>PersonId: </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBox("PersonId")
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name: </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBox("Name")
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2><input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javasript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("PersonId", $("#PersonId").val());
            formData.append("Name", $("#Name").val());
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Controller/Action",
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData,
                success: function (response) {
                    //alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```