# Загрузка данных на страницу по мере выбора пользователем вариантов asp net core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp-net-core-mvc

Проект asp net core 3.1, Entity framework core 3. Проект с представлениями mvc.

Есть 3 сущности - Friend, City, Street:

```
[Table("friend")]
    public partial class Friend
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id_Friend")]
        public long IdFriend { get; set; }
        [Column("Name_", TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column("City_id")]
        public int? CityId { get; set; }
        [Column("Street_id")]
        public int? StreetId { get; set; }
        [Column("User_id")]
        public long? UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(CityId))]
        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public virtual City City { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(StreetId))]
        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public virtual Street Street { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }


[Table("city")]
    public partial class City
    {
        public City()
        {
            Friends = new HashSet<Friend>();
            Streets = new HashSet<Street>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("Id_City")]
        public int IdCity { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("City")]
        public virtual ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("City")]
        public virtual ICollection<Street> Streets { get; set; }
    }


[Table("street")]
    public partial class Street
    {
        public Street()
        {
            Friends = new HashSet<Friend>();
            Houses = new HashSet<House>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("Id_Street")]
        public int IdStreet { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column("City_id")]
        public int? CityId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(CityId))]
        [InverseProperty("Streets")]
        public virtual City City { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Street")]
        public virtual ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Street")]
        public virtual ICollection<House> Houses { get; set; }
    }
```

По плану пользователь добавляет друга (Friend) и вводит данные о нем - имя, город, улицу, номер дома.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы на странице представления при выборе пользователем города в поле с улицей подгружался список улиц, относящихся к данному городу - из коллекции ICollection Streets объекта сущности Friends, а не весь список улиц?

Страница представления:

```
<h4>Friend</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="IdFriend" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CityId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CityId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CityId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="CityId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StreetId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="StreetId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StreetId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="StreetId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="HouseId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="HouseId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.HouseId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="HouseId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.UserId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="UserId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: Это делается при помощи ajax-запроса который вешается на событие onChange списка: в js делаете обращение к контроллеру передавая ему cityId и как получите удаляете все `<options` из второго списка, заливая новые. Примерные куски можно посмотреть тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/803903/213987 или тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/965703/213987 Также разберите пример отсюда https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/17.php Альтернативный вариант - разово скачать все города и дальнейшую фильтрацию проводить через js скрывая "лишние" города. В общем, в любом случае придётся на javascript пописать.

Comment: @Ak, спасибо, буду разбираться. А на mvc контроллере и mvc представление это получится сделать или придется писать APIController?

Comment: Получится, в этом плане api контроллеры ничем принципиально от mvc'шных не отличаются.